# Travis CI, Static IP for the VM

Tags: travis-ci, static-ip-address

I want to use travis ci for testing a library, but it requires access to an api, that has to explicitly allow IP address to access it.

Is there a way to configure travis to use only one external IP, either free or in the paid version?

What I need is to be sure that the external IP of the VM in travis is always one of a small set of predefined IPs.

I don't really want to configure proxies and such, although if push comes to shove, that's what I'll probably do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make the VMs use a single IP. We do have a subnet that we are currently using, but this can change at any time, so that option wouldn't be ideal either. Out of the options you mentioned, sounds like a proxy is the best solution.

Comment: Well 10x anyway :) Any reliable proxy server for open source come to mind?

Comment: What is the subnet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497826/travis-ci-pro-cidr-ip-range

Comment: Just in case someone runs into this and becomes misinformed, there are ways to make VMs use the same IP (even across separate hardware devices). Seems like this is specifically an internal issue at Travis.