# Travis CI/Pro: CIDR/IP Range?

Tags: travis-ci, amazon-redshift

We are using Travis Pro and we have some tests against Redshift. Is there a CIDR/IP range for Travis VMs that we can create a security rule for in Redshift? Obviously we won't open Redshift for any incoming IP...

Answer (score 0):

This used to be not possible but with Travis' [introduction](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-12-17-faster-builds-with-container-based-infrastructure/) of their new container-based infrastructure, they now **publish the IP ranges** of their machines. You can find them here:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ip-addresses/

For Travis Pro, you'd need to take the IP range listed for `travis-ci.com`; open source projects need those for `travis-ci.org`. There are still no fixed IP ranges in case you're using their **legacy infrastructure**. If your project does not require `sudo`, have a look at their [migration guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrating-from-legacy/).